# how can have the full value of a fraction instead of receiving it with e in Swift?

Tags: swift

I have a value of type Double I want print the full value! But it prints with **e**, how can I get value with all zeros, without any other change on it or any rounding?

```
let value: Double = 0.0000000001

print(value)  // It prints: 1e-10 But I want: 0.0000000001
```

Comment: Lookup `NumberFormatter` ...

Comment: Also be aware that trying to represent a fractional value using Double or Float can introduce a degree of inaccuracy due to trying to represent the fractional value with a binary structure.  if absolute precision is required consider the `Decimal` data type.

Comment: @flanker: about inaccuracy you mentioned, is it going happening when we are trying to use `NumberFormatter` or it happens here or there even without converting and just using the Double type with value of `0.0000000001`, which one?

Comment: Binary representations of floating point numbers will always have some inaccuracy. Internally, a Double will store a value very close to 0.0000000001, but not exact. It has to do with the way binary floating point works. They store sums of fractional powers of 2, 1/2, 1/4, 1/8,  1/16, etc. You can't represent 0.1 exactly in a binary floating point number, because 1/10 can't be represented as a sum of fractions of powers of 2. You can get very close, but not exact.

Comment: @flanker, even Decimal has limits. It can't represent values like 1/3 exactly.

Comment: @DuncanC: can you gave or show an inaccuracy case of using Double in the way you mentioned?

Comment: Sure. Try this: `let value = 200.1 - 200` then `print(value)`

Comment: @DuncanC Fair point about 1/3, but even standard written decimal notation can't cope with that without the 'recurring' notation.  And thanks for picking up the answer for me.

Comment: @DuncanC: I tried your given code, it has indeed inaccuracy! why this simple and easy math has inaccuracy? how could we solve this issue?

Comment: If you log the result using a NumberFormatter or format string it rounds it and hides the error.  Change the print statement to `print(String(String(format: "%0.12lf", value)))
` and it will display correctly, even to 12 decimal places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binary floating point has error inherent in it. It has to do with the way it works.

Decimal math has error as well. You can't represent 1/3 exactly in decimal. The answer is 0.33̄ (point 3, repeating forever.) That's because base 10 does not have a way to represent thirds exactly. Only sums of fractions of 2 and 5.

Binary floating point is worse. Each binary digit represents a smaller fraction of 2 (1 over a power of 2)

So you can add 1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/16, 1/32, 1/64, 1/128, etc to your fractional value, but never 5ths, or 10ths. In binary, 0.1 is a repeating value.

Representing 0.1 in binary fractions, we will use 0.xxxx, where each digit after the dot is either a 0 or a 1. Each following place is 1 over a larger power of 2. It comes to 0.0001̄1̄0̄0̄ (where the 1100 part repeats forever.)

There is a special data type, `Decimal`, that lets you do base decimal math without encountering binary floating point errors. It is much slower than binary floating point, but it doesn't have the conversion errors that binary floating point does. Search on `Decimal` in the Xcode docs for more info.

You can also use the `String(format:)` initializer to convert numbers to strings with a certain number of decimal places. That function rounds away the small errors so your calculations look correct.

Consider this code:

```
let value = 200.1 - 200
print("value = ", terminator: ""); print(value)
print("Using `String(format:)`, value = " + String(format: "%lf", value))

let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
print("Using NumberFormatter, value = " + numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: value))!)
```

That outputs:

```
value = 0.09999999999999432
Using `String(format:)`, value = 0.100000
Using NumberFormatter, value = 0.1
```

The value in `value` is still a tiny bit off from exactly 0.1, but converting it to a string rounds it slightly, hiding the tiny error.

### Edit:

If you want to display very small values like 0.0000000001, use

```
String(format: "%.10lf", value))
```

(Where the number between the dot and the “lf” is the desired number of decimal places

Comment: As you gave an example in your answer like `value = 0.09999999999999432` or as I gave an example in my question like `let value: Double = 0.0000000001` I want the String format of it whit out any change or rounding, I learned about inaccuracy topic from you and it was interesting, but my goal in my question is reflecting the string format of the value. with your answer i get zero!